# Spring cloud sleuth: integrating with correlation id in other header key (not X-Trace-Id but e.g. myCorrelationId)

Tags: spring-cloud

We have an existing correlation id feature that stores a correlation id in the `myCorrelationId` HTTP header (and similarly in the JMS Context, SOAP Header, etc.). This feature is used in a number of applications.

It would be nice to use spring sleuth for new applications and to be able to interoperate with existing applications.

As far as I understand spring cloud sleuth, it does not yet offer such integration (the key `X-Trace-Id` to lookup a potentially existing correlation id is hardcoded and not abstracted in one central place).

I understand your concern about occupying too many header keys (https://gitlab.com/dsyer/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/11). Support for mapping incoming correlation ids (i.e. mapping the content of `myCorrelationId` to `X-Trace-Id`) would already fix some cases.

Do you plan to support such an integration? How would you adapt sleuth for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work in progress - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/19 . We're doing our best to have it done for RC1.

Comment: Customization is ready in the current snapshot version - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_customizations

Comment: You can check out the latest RC1